# How do I cite the authors of a web page that is maintained by Google and other contributors (APA style)?

Tags: citations, authorship, website

I have to cite a web page in my thesis and I am unsure how to do it. Unfortunately, I could not find anything helpful for my specific problem.

The website is maintained by Google, but Google also allows others to contribute to the website. Those additional contributors are not specifically mentioned on the website. Do I need to cite these contributors and add them to the bibliography as authors? If yes, how should I name them?

I have thought about the following things:

- Name the other contributors simply as 'other contributors'
- Group Google and the other contributors together as 'WEBSITE_NAME website contributors'
- Leave the other contributors out because they are not specifically mentioned in the website maintained by Google

What do you think? Any inputs?